# How to implement fn:QName in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am in the process of converting a file written in XSLT 2.0 to XSLT 1.0 so that it can be used in a browser. Would anyone know how to implement something with the same functionality as fn:Qname using only XSLT 1.0?

Comment: There are ways (Saxon-CE, Saxon-JS) to run XSLT 2.0 in the browser, it might be an easier approach than trying to implement parts of XSLT and XPath 2.0 on your own in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for the suggestion. It was my impression that the Saxon solutions can only read pre-compiled SEF files. Is it possible to use them without purchasing a Saxon EE license?

Comment: http://saxonica.com/ce/index.xml is open source and does not require compiling stylesheets with Saxon EE. Saxon-JS, on the other hand, does require that. Note however that some tools like oXygen come with Saxon EE and the ability to compile stylesheets so any oXygen user can create and compile stylesheets for Saxon-JS.

Comment: @MaxChemtov It would be helpful to know what are you using the `Qname()` function for. There is no XPath/XSLT 1.0 equivalent - but the same functionality may be achieved using a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

`fn:QName` delivers a value of type `xs:QName`, and there is no such data type in XSLT 1.0, so there can be no equivalent function. You'll have to start by deciding on an alternative representation of QNames: for example you could use the XPath 3.0 notation "Q{uri}local", held as a string. (The xs:QName type also holds a namespace prefix, you need to decide whether you need to do that.)

Assuming you decide to use the representation "Q{uri}local" and that namespace prefixes are not required, implementing an equivalent of `fn:QName` can then be done straightforwardly using functions such as `concat()`, `contains()`, and `substring-after()`.